# Why I can't access .playAndRecord

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to play a sound in Swift 4 iOS 12 with Xcode 10. I have a project where I already did that and I'm copying the code from that project.

But now when executing the following code:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
```

I get the following error in this exact line:

> Type 'AVAudioSession.Category' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'playAndRecord'

I already imported AVFoundation so I have no idea is not working.

Comment: The code you posted is for Swift 4.2, not Swift 4.

Answer (score 5):

I face the same issue, I was working in swift v4 and the code you are using is for Swift 4.2
You have to use the following string AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord in place of playAndRecord

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat, options: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
        try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Comment: Your explanation helped me to get the exact reason of the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can use 'AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord'

Comment: Instead of writing *"use {something}"* explain or show example how it solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the code from Apple website.
[AVAudioSession Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession)

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
} catch {
    print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord failed.")
}
```